# Restricting access to a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, security

I have a subfolder in my project. I want only the users with roles to enter it.. how do i achieve it while redirecting the user to the login page..This is what i have so far in the webconfig in the subdirectory

(i have another web.config in the virtual directory of my project)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="Moderator"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the behavior now with your current code?

Comment: It throws the anonymous user to the registration page and doesnt allow him to enter the site :( ...

Comment: The <deny users="*"/> tag is restricting anon users and <deny users="?"/> is restricting auth'd users (except users with the Moderator role).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, in the root web.config, add this to the bottom. No need for the second web.config then.

```
<location path="SubFolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow roles="Moderator"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: That doensnt work well..cause i already have one authentication..and i told i cant use two web.config with two authentication sections

Comment: Edited, use location tag at the bottom of the main web.config file